# Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil on OS X along with Maven in JavaCV

Tags: java, maven, opencv, javacv

I have added the following dependancies to my maven project.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacpp</artifactId>
        <version>0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
        <version>0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.10-0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>ffmpeg</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1-0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>flycapture</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3.13-0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>libdc1394</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2-0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>libfreenect</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.1-0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>videoinput</artifactId>
        <version>0.200-0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>artoolkitplus</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1-0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>flandmark</artifactId>
        <version>1.07-0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>fftw</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4-0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>gsl</artifactId>
        <version>1.16-0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>llvm</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0-0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>leptonica</artifactId>
        <version>1.71-0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>tesseract</artifactId>
        <version>3.03-rc1-0.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

And ran the code mentioned [here](http://opencvlover.blogspot.com/2012/05/importing-video-using-javacv.html). I used FFmpegFrameGrabber instead of OpenCVFrameGra

I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:385)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:353)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avformat$AVFormatContext.<clinit>(avformat.java:2249)
at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.startUnsafe(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:346)
at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.start(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:340)
```

Any Idea ? I am on OS X Yosemite with JDK 1.7.

Comment: Have you set the `platform.dependencies` system property?

Comment: Yes, it worked after that. Thanks. But wont that make the application that I am making platform dependent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Samuel Audet mentioned, this issue got solved after using the "platform.dependencies" property. eg :

```
 $ mvn package exec:java -Dplatform.dependencies -Dexec.mainClass=Demo
```

Comment: How to do this if i'm using gradle(AndroidStudio)?