# NoClassDefFoundError but class exist after deployment of WAR file

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tesseract

I have a servlet based application and it works, when I run it from within Eclipse. I've created a WAR file and deployed it to Tomcat. After deployment I find the unpacked files of my WAR project in webapps/ directory.

But when I try open the servlet, via url, I get the following error:

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.javacpp.tesseract$TessBaseAPI
com.gorcer.iseeyou.FounderMgr.prepareEnv(FounderMgr.java:80)
com.gorcer.iseeyou.Api.doGet(Api.java:54)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.56 (Debian) logs.
```

Full stack:

```
май 19, 2016 5:52:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ApiServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.javacpp.tesseract$TessBaseAPI
    at com.gorcer.iseeyou.FounderMgr.prepareEnv(FounderMgr.java:80)
    at com.gorcer.iseeyou.Api.doGet(Api.java:54)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I looked at WEB-INF/lib and found "tesseract-3.04-1.1.jar". It contains the missing class named "tesseract$TessBaseAPI.class".

Why isn't it included?

Comment: can you please post your full stack of exception?

Comment: For some reason the classloader is not loading that class. Take a look at <TOMCAT_HOME>/logs/catalina.log to see if you can get a better idea as to why.

Comment: Would you please put your tesseract-3.04-1.1.jar to tomcat lib and try again? Hope problem will be resolved.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733142/could-not-initialize-class-org-bytedeco-javacpp-avutil-on-os-x-along-with-maven

Comment: thank's @tak3shi , it's help for me.